# Which NetTopologySuite Index is optimal for include and exclude rectangle search

Tags: spatial-index, nettopologysuite

I have a following problem: huge number of points and huge number of queries which need to provide as fast as possible any point that is inside include rectangle (red) and outside exclude rectangle (green). As number of points is huge and rectangles can be of various sizes it would be best to use some spatial index, but as far as I see all *Query* functions in *NetTopologySuite.Index* return lists with all results, where I need any single result and so queries are too expensive when big rectangle with many points comes.

Did I miss some spatial index which will solve my problem? Or some nice trick to solve it fast? I could use visitors but they are evaluated for every node, I could use Exception to break out when element found, but that looks ugly.

[image: visualization]

Answer (score 1):

You can query the indices using a custom `IItemVisitor{T}` that would exclude items intersecting the green rectangle. Sth along these lines:

```
/// <summary>
/// Item visitor that specifically excludes a predefined area.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items to visit</typeparam>
public class ExcludingItemVisitor<T> : IItemVisitor<T> where T:Geometry
{
    private readonly Envelope _exclude;
    private readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize with <paramref name="exclude"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exclude"></param>
    public ExcludingItemVisitor(Envelope exclude)
    {
        _exclude = exclude;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="IItemVisitor{T}.VisitItem"/>>
    public void VisitItem(T item)
    {
        // If we have no intersection with _exclude, add it.
        if (!_exclude.Intersects(item.EnvelopeInternal))
            _items.Add(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a value indicating the gathered items
    /// </summary>
    public IList<T> Items => _items;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have used In end, but this is also described in question. It is too expensive to collect all, so I have thrown exception for first one which is not in exclude rect.

Comment: You are right, there currently is no shortcut to abort the query when any item is found.

Comment: Thx, coming from is reassuring as I recall you being top contributor on NTS git repo :)